# Do I need to use approve method in ERC721?

Tags: nft, vyper

I am practicing the smart contract and NFT looks interested to me. 
[ERC721 written in Vyper](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/master/examples/tokens/ERC721.vy)

What is the mechanic of approve in it?
What is `isApprovedForAll` does?

IMO. I don't need to use approve method. I just use `transferFrom()` is enough.
Correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approval mechanism is described in more depth in the [ERC-721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) standard.

> *What is the mechanic of approve in it?*

A token owner can approve another address (an operator) to spend a specific token using the `approve()` function, as well as all of the owner's tokens using `setApprovalForAll()`.

> *What is `isApprovedForAll` does?*

It's a getter function returning `bool` value whether an operator address can spend all of the owner tokens (i.e. they have been approved using the `setApprovalForAll()` function) - or not.

> *I don't need to use approve method. I just use transferFrom() is enough.*

Correct if you're only spending your own tokens.

If you want another address to spend your tokens, or if you want to spend tokens belonging to another owner (possibly one of your other addresses), you'll need to use the approval mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, with `***approve()***` the transfer happens in 2 steps:

You, the owner, call approve and give it the `_approved` address of the new owner, and the `_tokenId` you want them to take.

The new owner calls `transferFrom` with the `_tokenId`. Next, the contract checks to make sure the new owner has been already approved, and then transfers them the token.